# cake 2.5.1 bind 2 models together

Tags: cakephp

I have a model Ranking which holds a contact_id and belongsTo Model Contact.
Model Contact has a costumer_id and belongsTo Model Costumer.
And hasMany Rankings.

There is also a Model Product which hasMany Ranking.

On a statistics page I select

```
$this->Product->recursive = 1;
$this->set('products', $this->Paginator->paginate())
```

;

and I get the array of

```
array(
    'Product' => array(
        'id' => '69',
    ),
    'Ranking' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '29',
            'contact_id' => '9',
            'product_id' => '69',
            'ranking' => '9',
        ),
```

I would like to bind now the Contact and Costumer to the ranking based on the contact_id.
Is this manually possible via bindModel?
If yes, how can I do that?

I tried to set $this->Product->recursive = 1; to 2 and 3, but that select so many other things which I would need to clear with unbindModel... So I hope there is a smarter way of bind those model to get to the data...?

Answer (score 0):

What you basically want to use is [containable behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html). With this behavior you are able to filter and limit model find operations. You have the possibility to add this behavior on model level or at the controller to avoid side effects if the application has already grown to a complicated level.

Example from [Cake-Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containing-deeper-associations):

```
// Activate Containable Behavior on the fly in a controller
$this->User->Behaviors->load('Containable');
$this->User->contain();

$this->User->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Profile',
        'Account' => array(
            'AccountSummary'
        ),
        'Post' => array(
            'PostAttachment' => array(
                'fields' => array('id', 'name'),
                'PostAttachmentHistory' => array(
                    'HistoryNotes' => array(
                        'fields' => array('id', 'note')
                    )
                )
            ),
            'Tag' => array(
                'conditions' => array('Tag.name LIKE' => '%happy%')
            )
        )
    )
));
```

Hope this gives you a push into the right direction.

Comment: Maybe I am still on the wrong path. I set actas contaible in Ranking model and added $this->Paginator->settings['contain'] = array(
                'Contact' => array(
                    'Costumer'
                )
            );
to the paginator conditions. But with no success...

Comment: I would suggest to leave the paginator out for the moment and check if you get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

using find it will get me the right data with this:

```
$this->set('products', $this->Product->find('all', array(
            'contain' => array(
                'Ranking' => array(
                    'Contact' => array(
                        'foreignKey' => 'contact_id',
                        'Customer' => array(
                            'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )));
```

When using the Paginator it looks like

```
$this->Paginator->settings['contain'] = array(
                'Ranking' => array(
                    'Contact' => array(
                        'foreignKey' => 'contact_id',
                        'Customer' => array(
                            'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
                        )
                    )
                )
           );

$this->Product->Behaviors->load('Containable');
        $this->set('products', $this->Paginator->paginate());
```

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Hi,

right now cake is doing a query for getting the PRODUCT. Another one for getting the RANKING and then for each RANKING one for the contact and one for the customer...  is there no combination possible to integrate those queries related to contact and customer into the rankings query? To save all those queries?